# The number of ways to make $20$ out of coins of given value

Tags: combinatorics

Say, in one country there is currency called $X$. It is given that the country's bank produces 
the following coins:

- $0.1X$
- $0.5X$
- $1X$
- $2X$
- $5X$
- $10X$

Example:
For $0.6X$ there are 2 possibilities: $0.1X + 0.5X$ and $6\times0.1X$.

The question is how many ways there are for combining $20X$?

Comment: I assume those dashes are not minus signs.  The easiest solution uses generating functions.

Comment: An idea: 20X = 200 * 0.1X. So you have 200 "base blocks" to work with. Then see how many ways you can combine blocks to form bigger blocks. The bigger blocks are: 0.5X = 5 * 0.1X, 1X = 10 * 0.1X, 2X = 20 * 0.1X, 5X = 50 * 0.1X, 10X = 100 * 0.1X.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it both lacks detail and it's a template-duplicate of other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the power series for the following functions:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^{.1}},\frac{1}{1-x^{.5}},\frac{1}{1-x},\frac{1}{1-x^2},\frac{1}{1-x^5},\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}.
$$

The answer that you're looking for is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the power series expansion of the product of these functions (to get Maple to compute this, I had to multiply all the exponents by 10 and ask for the 200th Taylor coefficient at $0$).

The reason for this is that the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$, so the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x^{\alpha}}$ is $1+x^{\alpha}+x^{2\alpha}+x^{3\alpha}+\cdots$.  A product of elements of this form which gives $x^{20}$ looks like:

$$
x^{20}=x^{a_1\cdot .1}x^{a_2\cdot .5}x^{a_3\cdot 1}x^{a_4\cdot 2}x^{a_5\cdot 5}x^{a_6\cdot 10}=x^{a_1\cdot .1+a_2\cdot .5+a_3\cdot 1+a_4\cdot 2+a_5\cdot 5+a_6\cdot 10}.
$$

Where the $a_i$'s are nonnegative integers.  Therefore, every combination that adds to 20 is represented exactly once in a combination adding to 20, so the coefficient counts the number of such sums.

As a check, the answer is 3274 (computed with Maple)

Comment: Would you like please to give the answer in number, this field is not my strongest one, I am beginner at it...?

Comment: It is 3274, @DimaBookshpan.